# How to access a port on a remote server using SSH?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have a service running on a certain port at the server. What I want to do is, access the server using SSH and use a local (client-side) program to access the server's port. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to a port on a server via an ssh tunnel can be done with the `-L` local port forwarding option.

For example, to connect to www.example.com:80 & to make it available on the client as port  `8080`, you would do:

```
ssh -L8080:127.0.0.1:80 www.example.com
```

This allows you to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser & have `www.example.com:80` available. You can also have `www.example.com` connect to another host instead of itself, making the tunnel into a proxy.